# How to clear but not delete all files in all subfolders with exception of the batch file?

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

I have already this batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Are you sure (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END
@echo off
pushd %*
for %%j in (*) do if /I not "%%j"=="%~nx0" type nul > "%%j"
popd
```

I want to create a 0 byte backup of all files in all subfolders. So if I lose them I would know what to re-download. The batch file itself should not be cleared.

What must be changed on this code to run on all files in all subfolders?

Comment: You want to clear all files in all subfolders but leave the bat itself untouched, right?

Comment: Yes i actually do, i wanted to create a 0-byte backup of some files so if i lose them i'd know what to re-download..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FORFILES` is your friend! The syntax is:

`forfiles [/p <Path>] [/m <SearchMask>] [/s] [/c "<Command>"] [/d [{+|-}][{<Date>|<Days>}]]`

The `/s` option will make your script look into subfolders. This should work:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE=Are you sure (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END
FORFILES /S /C "CMD /C IF @ISDIR==FALSE IF NOT @FILE==\"%~nx0\" type nul > @PATH"
```

Possible variables in FORFILES construct are:

- `@FILE`: File name.
- `@FNAME`: File name without extension.
- `@EXT`: File name extension.
- `@PATH`: Full path of the file.
- `@RELPATH`: Relative path of the file.
- `@ISDIR`: Evaluates to TRUE if a file type is a directory. Otherwise, this variable evaluates to FALSE.
- `@FSIZE`: File size, in bytes.
- `@FDATE`: Last modified date stamp on the file.
- `@FTIME`: Last modified time stamp on the file.

For more information check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx.

EDIT: Added skip if folder

Comment: Edited the answer to skip folders.